# Finding 10 longest words that are in both text files c#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, oop, text

I have two different text files and I have to find 10 longest words that are in both of them. I have to print the list of those words out and write the frequency - how many times they are repeated in those separate files. The problem I have with my current code is that it finds the words, but when it comes to frequency - it combines the frequency count. How can I change the code to know the frequency count for separate files?

Here is my code for finding words that are in both text files:

```
        public static Dictionary<string, int> PopularWords(string data1, string data2, char[] punctuation)
        {
            string[] book1 = data1.Split(punctuation, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] book2 = data2.Split(punctuation, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Dictionary<string, int> matches = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < book1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (matches.ContainsKey(book1[i]))
                {
                    matches[book1[i]]++;
                    continue;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < book2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (book1[i] == book2[j])
                    {
                        if (matches.ContainsKey(book1[i]))
                        {
                            matches[book1[i]]++;
                        } else
                        {
                            matches.Add(book1[i], 2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return matches;
```

And here is my code for reading and printing:

```
        public static void ProcessPopular(string data, string data1, string results)
        {
            char[] punctuation = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\n' };
            string lines = File.ReadAllText(data, Encoding.UTF8);
            string lines2 = File.ReadAllText(data1, Encoding.UTF8);

            var popular = PopularWords(lines, lines2, punctuation);

            KeyValuePair<string, int>[] popularWords = popular.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(popularWords, (x, y) => y.Key.Length.CompareTo(x.Key.Length));

            using (var writerF = File.CreateText(results))
            {
                int foundWords = 0;
                writerF.WriteLine("{0, -25} | {1, -35} | {2, -35}", "Longest words", "Frequency in 1 .txt file", "Frequency in 2 .txt file");
                writerF.WriteLine(new string('-', 101));

                // not finished
            }
        }
```

Comment: Store two `int`s in the `Dictionary` entry for a word, using a `class` two hold two counts, one for each book.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> PopularWords(string data1, string data2, char[] punctuation)
{
    string[] book1 = data1.Split(punctuation, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] book2 = data2.Split(punctuation, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return
        Enumerable
            .Concat(
                book1.Select(x => (word: x, book: "book1")),
                book2.Select(x => (word: x, book: "book2")))
            .ToLookup(x => x.word, x => x.book)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Length)
            .Take(10)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.GroupBy(y => y).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Count())); ;
}
```

If I start with this data:

```
char[] punctuation = new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '-', ':' };
string data1 = "I have two different text files and I have to find 10 longest words that are in both of them. I have to print the list of those words out and write the frequency - how many times they are repeated in those separate files. The problem I have with my current code is that it finds the words, but when it comes to frequency - it combines the frequency count. How can I change the code to know the frequency count for separate files?";
string data2 = "This solution is more general: it works whatever number of files you wish to process. This is an extremely raw query that could be separated in smaller queries, but it gives the logical basis. Other requirements, like only 10 words or minimum word length etc can be easily applied. Please do mind that this a bare-bone example, without any safety checks. It also omits reading data from files. The problem I have with my current code is that it finds the words, but when it comes to frequency - it combines the frequency count. How can I change the code to know the frequency count for separate files?";
```

I get this result:

```
"requirements": { "book2" = 1 }
"different": { "book1" = 1 }
"frequency": { "book1" = 4, "book2" = 3 }
"extremely": { "book2" = 1 }
"separated": { "book2" = 1 }
"repeated": { "book1" = 1 }
"separate": { "book1" = 2, "book2" = 1 }
"combines": { "book1" = 1, "book2" = 1 }
"solution": { "book2" = 1 }
"whatever": { "book2" = 1 }
```

Comment: Only looking at your result, it seems your answer finds the 10 longest words, not the "10 longest words that are in both of them."

Comment: @LaurentGabiot - I read that as the same thing. If it said the "10 longest words that are in ***each*** of them" then I would have done it differently.

Comment: Ok, I get it (sorry english is not my mother tongue). I failed to read it this way. I wish the OP would clarify this.

Comment: @LaurentGabiot - I too thought the OP was a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, if performance is not the key here, I would go this way:

```
public static void Method()
{
    var a = "A deep blue raffle, very deep and blue, raffle raffle. An old one was there";
    var b = "deep blue raffle, very very very long and blue, raffle RAFFLE. A new one was there";
    char[] punctuation = { '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\n' };

    var fileOne = new string(a.Where(c => punctuation.Contains(c) is false).ToArray()).Split(" ");
    var fileTwo = new string(b.Where(c => punctuation.Contains(c) is false).ToArray()).Split(" ");
    var duplicates = fileOne.Intersect(fileTwo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var result = new List<(int, int, string)>(duplicates.Count());


    foreach(var duplicat in duplicates)
    {
        result.Add((fileOne.Count(x => x.Equals(duplicat, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), fileTwo.Count(x => x.Equals(duplicat, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), duplicat));
    }

    foreach (var val in result)
    {
        Output.WriteLine($"Word: {val.Item3} | In file one: {val.Item1} | In file two: {val.Item2}");
    }
}
```

This will give you the result of

> Word: A | In file one: 1 | In file two: 1
> Word: deep | In file one: 2 | In file two: 1
> Word: blue | In file one: 2 | In file two: 2
> Word: raffle | In file one: 3 | In file two: 3
> Word: very | In file one: 1 | In file two: 3
> Word: and | In file one: 1 | In file two: 1
> Word: one | In file one: 1 | In file two: 1
> Word: was | In file one: 1 | In file two: 1
> Word: there | In file one: 1 | In file two: 1

Other requirements, like only 10 words or minimum word length etc can be easily applied.

Please do mind that this a bare-bone example, without any safety checks. It also omits reading data from files.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I was not very pleased with my original solution, so I reworked it. I abandonned one thing I liked in my previous solution: the fact that it didn't depend on an external list of punctuation characters, but that this list was generated by the query itself. But it made the query more complicated and long.

In case you would be curious about a different coding style, here is a solution using Linq.

This solution is more general: it works whatever number of files you wish to process.

This is a Linqpad query that you can run directly via copy/paste, but you need to provide the text files of course:

```cs
// Choose here how many different words you want.
var resultCount = 10;
// Add as many files as needed.
var Files = new List<string>
{
    @"C:\Temp\FileA.txt",
    @"C:\Temp\FileB.txt",
    @"C:\Temp\FileC.txt",
};

char[] punctuation = { '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\n', '"', ' ' };

// Perform the calculation.
var LongestCommonWords = Files
    .SelectMany(f => File.ReadAllText(f)
            .Split(punctuation, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
            .ToLookup(w => ( word: w.ToLower(), fileName: f))
    )
    .ToLookup(e => e.Key.word)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == Files.Count())
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Length)
    .Take(resultCount);                     // Take only the desired amount (10 for instance)

// Display the results.
foreach (var word in LongestCommonWords)
{
    var occurences = string.Join(" / ", word.Select(g => $"{Path.GetFileName(g.Key.fileName)} - {g.Count()}"));
    Console.WriteLine($"{word.Key} - {occurences}");
}
```

Here is an output obtained with the content of three Wikipedia pages:

> contribution - FileA.txt - 9 / FileB.txt - 1 / FileC.txt - 5
>
> subsequently - FileA.txt - 2 / FileB.txt - 1 / FileC.txt - 1
>
> introduction - FileA.txt - 1 / FileB.txt - 4 / FileC.txt - 3
>
> alternative - FileA.txt - 2 / FileB.txt - 1 / FileC.txt - 1
>
> independent - FileA.txt - 5 / FileB.txt - 3 / FileC.txt - 3
>
> significant - FileA.txt - 2 / FileB.txt - 1 / FileC.txt - 3
>
> established - FileA.txt - 1 / FileB.txt - 1 / FileC.txt - 1
>
> outstanding - FileA.txt - 1 / FileB.txt - 3 / FileC.txt - 3
>
> programming - FileA.txt - 1 / FileB.txt - 2 / FileC.txt - 4
>
> university - FileA.txt - 44 / FileB.txt - 17 / FileC.txt - 7